# flow-tools protocol numbers

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

When using flow-print to print the netflows into ASCII, I get 3 different values for protocols, ie protocol 1,6,17 ?
What does that mean ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably 1 is for ICMP, 6 is for TCP and 17 is for UDP. Refer to the [List of IP protocol numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers).